# mysql return date by top position

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table called scores:

```
userid    score    date
|1|1|2017-09-31
|1|1|2017-10-01
|2|2|2017-10-01
|1|2|2017-10-02
|2|2|2017-10-02
|3|1|2017-10-02
```

I would like to write a mysql query to return the date based ranking position 
( you pass user_id & rank position like 1 , 2 , 3 etc and it will return array of dates)

```
2017-09-31 will be return for user ID 1 , position #1
2017-10-01
user 2  is #1 
user 1  is #2

2017-10-02
user 1 & 2 are both position 1 & 2
user 3 is after
```

how could I do this?

Comment: Read [How to Ask A Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For `2017-10-02`, both user ids  1 & 2 having the same score. So the rank should be same right?

Comment: yes it should be the same,

Comment: to explain it better , you pass user_id and position # to the SQL and it will return array dates for you

Comment: Altogether now: "Thirty days hath September..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,userid INT NOT NULL 
,date DATE NOT NULL
,score INT NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(userid,date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (userid,date,score) VALUES
(1,'2017-09-30',1),
(1,'2017-10-01',1),
(2,'2017-10-01',2),
(1,'2017-10-02',2),
(2,'2017-10-02',2),
(3,'2017-10-02',1);

SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(DISTINCT y.score) rank 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.date = x.date 
   AND y.score >= x.score 
 GROUP 
    BY x.date,x.userid 
HAVING rank = 1 AND userid = 1;
+--------+------------+-------+------+
| userid | date       | score | rank |
+--------+------------+-------+------+
|      1 | 2017-09-30 |     1 |    1 |
|      1 | 2017-10-02 |     2 |    1 |
+--------+------------+-------+------+
```

or

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.date = x.date 
   AND y.score >= x.score 
 GROUP 
    BY x.date,x.userid 
HAVING userid = 1
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT y.score) = 1;
```

Comment: this looks good , but when user id = 3 and rank = 2 , it suppose to return no dates , since user id 3 has a rank of 3 on 2017-10-02 how to fix it

Comment: User 3 has a rank of 2 on that date. The other users are joint first.

Comment: Yes but can we change it where user 3 has rank 3 ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try that...

```
SELECT Distinct (userid), SUM(score) Summe
  FROM [YOURDATABASETABLE]
  where date <= '2017-10-02'
  group by userid
  order by Summe desc
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I dont need to get the Sum, I think you are confused, I dont want to pass the date to the sql, I am passing user_id and position # and it will return the date

Comment: yes i misunderstood... so you need to calculate positions for every date...

Comment: basically I need to pass user id and position and return the date if any that he was for that posiiton

Comment: Yes I understand now, but because you are not saving any history of the "ranking table" you have to calculate positions for each date for a user... in a second step you can query the rank/date you need

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: In SQL: unfortunately I don't know. By Code: should be easy... but still I'm quite convinced that this is not a way to solve your problem! Maybe there should be something like a daily ranking (over-night-batch) which is calculated with the last days figures and those of the current day. But you should not build something that has to calculate every value from the beginning of recordings to get to a simple result. This will grow and grow and it will take more time to process every day.

Comment: Distinct is not a function.